# Stopping Kernel Density from cutting off symbology?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, symbology, arcgis-10.2, kernel-density

I need help configuring Kernel Density so that is does not cut off symbology on hot spots. (See pic below) I'm assuming it has something to do with the extent but I could not get it to display the way I want it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: (1) What software are you using? (2) As far as I can see this is a question about controlling the drawing order (or possibly transparency) of layers on a map: what does it have to do with kernel density calculations or map extents?

Comment: I'm using ArcMap 10.2.1. The Kernel Density raster or "hot spots" are being cut off. I added another image to better explain what I'm talking about.

Comment: Can you ensure that there is no mask being set in the Environment Settings -> Raster Analysis and/or the Processing Extent?

Comment: The processing is set to Default and there are no masks. The only mask I am using is on the label text.

Comment: I added another picture of the raster before I changed the symbology. I am trying to figure out if there is a way to prevent the edges from being cut where there are hot spots.

Comment: If a search of our site for [spatial analyst extent environment](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=spatial+analyst+extent+environment) does not address your problem, then please tell us in more detail how you are producing these density calculations.

Comment: Thanks to all. I changed 'Processing extent' as 'Same as Display' and it works!!!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/95708)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default the extent of the output kernel is the same as the extent of the shapefile. This is why it appears to be getting clipped. You'll need to explicitly define the extent for the output.

The easiest way to do this in Arcmap may be to go to Geoprocessing -> Environment Settings, then select 'Processing Extent'. Select the input point layer, and adjust the numbers as you desire.

Comment: This resolved my issue. I set the Processing Extent to same as Display.